# Use existing hover CSS class to other html tags

Tags: html, css

I have a hover effect over some of my images.

At the moment the hover effect is active on the `figure` tag. I have now added a `picture` tag.

Is it possible to add the same CSS to the `picture` tag from the existing CSS, instead of have to write the whole CSS with the only change of adding `pciture` instead off `figure`.

```css
  figure{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
  }
  figure:hover+span {
    bottom: -36px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* Opacity for banner? */
  .hover5 figure img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  }
  .hover5 figure:hover img {
    opacity: .5;
  }
```

```html
<div class="hover5 column">
   <figure>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/425x218" alt="#" class="img-responsive"></img>
   </figure>
</div>



<div class="hover5 column">
  <picture>
      <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="https://placehold.it/300x244"></source>
      <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="https://placehold.it/300x320"></source>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x244" alt="#" style="width:100%;"></img>
  </picture>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what your actual question is. You know how CSS rules & selectors work? And that you can use a comma to separate multiple selectors in a rule?

Comment: Use comma separator https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_comma.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `figure` or `picture` you could use a more general selector: `> *`. This will target the child of `.hover5` no matter what element type it is.

```css
.hover5 > *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
  }
  .hover5 > *:hover+span {
    bottom: -36px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* Opacity for banner? */
  .hover5 > * img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  }
  .hover5 > *:hover img {
    opacity: .5;
  }
```

```html
<div class="hover5 column">
   <figure>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/425x218" alt="#" class="img-responsive"></img>
   </figure>
</div>



<div class="hover5 column">
  <picture>
      <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="https://placehold.it/300x244"></source>
      <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="https://placehold.it/300x320"></source>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x244" alt="#" style="width:100%;"></img>
  </picture>
</div>
```

Comment: This is too broad, creating a class would be the cleanest solution.

Comment: @RutgervanDijk but would require changing the markup, possibly in many places.

Answer (score 2):

Where possible try to avoid targeting the HTML element's specifically. Build up a set of class names that you can put any element.

```
.your-hover-style:hover {

}
```

Or if you have to target the HTML element, then you can comma separate them.

```
figure, picture {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
figure{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  /* Opacity for banner? */
 img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
  }
 img:hover {
    opacity: .5;
  }
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/425x218" alt="#" class="img-responsive"/>
</figure>



<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="https://placehold.it/1200x400"/>
    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="https://placehold.it/380x500"/>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/1200x400" alt="#" style="width:100%;"/>
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to make a custom CSS class for this effect.

Let's call this class 'effect'. You can replace all the `figure` references in your CSS with `.effect`. And in your HTML turn the `<figure>` into `<figure class="effect">` and `<picture>` into `<picture class="effect">`